# How to map props to dropdown menu in Antd forms?

Tags: forms, reactjs, antd

I am trying to use a dropdown menu inside a form, using Ant design library. I didn't manage to map props to checkbox fields. Updates are (obviously) not taken by the field decorator, as I don't know how to bind the menu onSelect to the parent dropdown.

Quoting the docs :

> You can get the menu list by antd.Menu, and set a callback function onSelect for it if you need.

But it doesn't bind to props.
Any idea how to manage that use case?

```
function logSelection(value) {
 console.log(value)
}

const MenuIterable = (props) => {
  return (
    <Menu onSelect={props.selection}>
        {props.entries.map((e,i) => 
        <Menu.Item>
          <Checkbox checked={e.value} key={i}>
            {e.name}
          </Checkbox>
        </ Menu.Item>
      )}
    </Menu>
)}

const FormFilters = Form.create({

  onFieldsChange(props, changedFields) {
    props.onChange(changedFields);
  },
  mapPropsToFields(props) {
    return {
        itemType: {
            values: props.fields.itemType.values // [{name: "furniture", value:true}, ...]
    }
 };
}

})((props) => {
  const { getFieldDecorator } = props.form;

  return (
    <Form layout="inline">
      <FormItem label="">
        {getFieldDecorator('itemType', {
          rules: [{
            required: true,
            message: 'Item type required',
            initialValue:props.fields.itemType.values
          }],
        })(
            < Dropdown
              trigger={['click']}
              overlay={<MenuIterable selection={logSelection} entries={props.fields.itemType.values} />}
              onVisibleChange={props.fields.handleDropDown.bind(props.fields.dropDowns.itemType, { value:'itemType' })}
              visible={props.fields.dropDowns.itemType}
            >
                <a>
                  Item type <Icon type="down" />
                </a>
            </Dropdown>
        )}
      </FormItem>
    </Form>
  );
});

export default FormFilters;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you are saying "I don't know how to bind the menu onSelect to the parent dropdown" what exactly is it you want to bind? You are getting the `logSelection()` output, aren't you? It is in the `onSelect` function you should be handling the user selection, and propagate up to some kind of `handleChange` method of the form component.

You haven't included all the code, but the binding of `visible` and `onVisibleChange` to specific fields look weird. Normally `visible` is bound to a state boolean which you set from the `handleChange` method. This is why in the [docs](https://ant.design/components/dropdown/), the **"The way of hiding menu"** example (bottom one, right column) uses a Class component instead of a Functional.

Comment: I bound visible and onVisibleChange to external values because I have several dropdowns managed by the same container. Opening a dropdown must close the other ones!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Jesper, I had to

> propagate up to some kind of handleChange method of the form component

Antd Form component provides a `setFieldsValue` method, which allows to set field values and triggers the `onFieldsChange`form method.

It gives something like :

```
const MenuIterable = (props) => {
  return (
    <Menu onClick={props.selection}>
        {props.entries.map((e,i) =>
            <Menu.Item key={e.displayName}>
                <Checkbox checked={e.value} key={i}>{e.displayName}</Checkbox>
            </ Menu.Item>
        )}
        <Menu.Item key={'apply'}>
            <a type="primary">Apply</a>
        </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  )
}
```

And related dropdown :

```
              < Dropdown
                trigger={['click']}
                overlay={
                   <MenuIterable 
                      selection={(e) => refetchDataBasedOnCheckboxSelection.bind(props.form.setFieldsValue, e)}
                      entries={props.fields.itemType.values}
                   />
                }
              >
                <a>
                    Item types
                    <Icon type="down" />
                </a>
            </Dropdown>
```

There are some bugs related to `onSelect` triggering multiple times due to the presence of checkboxes inside selectable menu but I believe it's outside the scope of this question.

Thanks!